# Error when tring to show data from database php

Tags: php, xampp

This code i used in ampps and it worked but when i changed to xampp it gives me an error that i dont know.
My php is :

```
<?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';

 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM users";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($link, $sql_query);
 ?>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td><strong>descricao</strong></td>
   <td><strong>Tipo</strong></td>
   <td><strong>cenario</strong></td>
 </tr>
<?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){
 ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?=$row['descricao']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['Tipo_Divisao']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['cenario']?></td>
  </tr>
 <?
}
 ?>
</table>
```

And the erros is this:

```
Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\domotica\select.php on line 17,18,19
```

The include file is this:

```
<?php
   $host = "localhost";
   $user="root";
   $password="";
   $datbase="domotica";
   $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
   mysqli_select_db($link, $datbase);
 ?>
```

Comment: this code looks ok, check the included file

Comment: I putted the include file, i think it is right cause i can insert in database but i cant show the data